# Tornado nginx websockets handshake 400 error

Tags: python, nginx, websocket, tornado, sockjs

The problem is with websocket connection, proxied by nginx from tornado/tornado-sockjs to sockjs client in browser. Without nginx (on local host) things work properly.

Error message in browser when loading page (when sockjs connection initialized):

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://my-domain.com/ws/844/blvz89pq/websocket' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 400
```

Relevant part of custom nginx config:

```
location /ws/ {
  proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8888;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Value of $connection_upgrade from nginx.conf:

```
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        ''      close;
    }
```

It looks like tornado-sockjs returns 400 in case if `Upgrade`  header is not set to `'websocket'` ([code](https://github.com/mrjoes/sockjs-tornado/blob/8f01f943ee5ded0105bac009cbdf68e88846d630/sockjs/tornado/websocket.py#L46)). Indeed, printing headers before `if` in line 46 gives us value of header `Connection=close` and no `Upgrade` presented at all.

Value of `dict(self.request.headers)`

```
{
    "Accept-Language": "en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6", 
    "Accept-Encoding": "gzip, deflate, sdch", 
    "Sec-Websocket-Key": "*******", 
    "Connection": "close", 
    "X-Real-Ip": "172.17.0.1", 
    "Origin": "http://my-domain.com", 
    "Sec-Websocket-Extensions": "permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits", 
    "X-Forwarded-For": "172.17.0.1", 
    "Sec-Websocket-Version": "13", 
    "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36", 
    "Host": "my-domain.com", 
    "X-Forwarded-Proto": "http", 
    "Cookie": "_ym_uid=1456149826627418608; sessionid=0pn2knqey7raw7w4dst9d7vqvtvsmook; csrftoken=0o1lqSW4XCZvvlvYtN4S7Stt53AyKWf6; __utmx=147844469.bAGHuGeARZy_vppa6db8lg$115132382-10:5.mu9KcCiZSDepsLZ385hDXA$117448007-11:0; __utmxx=147844469.bAGHuGeARZy_vppa6db8lg$115132382-10:1456307221:15552000.mu9KcCiZSDepsLZ385hDXA$117458007-11:1457421562:15552000; _ym_isad=0; _ga=GA1.2.2002408319.1456149825; JSESSIONID=dummy", 
    "Pragma": "no-cache", 
    "Cache-Control": "no-cache"

}
```

But inspecting headers from browser shows, that both Connection and Upgrade headers have values, that should be valid for tornado.

Headers from browser:

```
Accept-Encoding:gzip, deflate, sdch
Accept-Language:en-US,en;q=0.8,ru;q=0.6
Cache-Control:no-cache
Connection:Upgrade
Cookie:_ym_uid=1456149826627418608; sessionid=0pn2knqey7raw7w4dst9d7vqvtvsmook; __utmx=147844469.bAGHuGeARZy_vppa6db8lg$115132382-10:5.mu9KcCiZSDepsLZ385hDXA$117448007-11:0; __utmxx=147844469.bAGHuGeARZy_vppa6db8lg$115132382-10:1456307221:15552000.mu9KcCiZSDepsLZ385hDXA$117448007-11:1457421562:15552000; _ym_isad=0; _ga=GA1.2.2002408319.1456149825; csrftoken=0o1lqSW4XCZvvlvYtN4S7Stt53AyKWf6; JSESSIONID=dummy
Host:my-domain.com
Origin:http://my-domain.com
Pragma:no-cache
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions:permessage-deflate; client_max_window_bits
Sec-WebSocket-Key:/zRJijtAtPjjLNJK49SIDQ==
Sec-WebSocket-Version:13
Upgrade:websocket
User-Agent:Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_3) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/48.0.2564.116 Safari/537.36
```

My possible suggestion is how/when Tornado parses headers.

UPD:
Versions of software used:

```
1. sockjs-tornado==1.0.2
2. tornado==4.3
3. tornado-redis==2.4.18
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

+1 to [Riliam](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2889812/riliam) [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35896872/987557), but I need to add my 5 cents, as this issue came back recently.
So to solve this issue, if you have **chief** nginx in front of nginx powered docker containers, you need to modify your **chief's** nginx config.

**/etc/nginx/nginx.conf**

```
...
map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
    default upgrade;
    ''      close;
}
...
```

**/etc/nginx/conf.d/virtual-site.conf**

8001 – port exposed from docker container

```
location / {
  proxy_pass         http://127.0.0.1:8001;

  proxy_http_version 1.1;
  proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
  proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;

  proxy_redirect     off;
  proxy_set_header   Host             $host;
  proxy_set_header   X-Real-IP        $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header   X-Forwarded-For  $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

So the problem was with proxying requests through one more Nginx running outside of Docker container.